# Activate Splash Activity or Main Activity based on the status of app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to open a specific file from another app with my app to handle it. For example, open a attached file in a mail from Gmail app.

With the following intent-filter setting, it works fine. When I open a file, MainActivity shows up and handles it irrespective of whether it is opened through another app or directly from my app. But I want the flow starting from SplashScreen Activity, in the event that the file is opened from another app. On the other hand, if app has been activated, activate directly MainActivity.

Does anyone know how to fix it??

> **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>         
</activity>

<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:mimeType="*/*"
            android:scheme="content" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: In your SplashActivity check for your condition, and if that condition is met, directly launch the MainActivity before setContentView() is called.

Comment: hi @Rachit, but if I want to resume the previous MainActivity state??

Comment: What previous state?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your activity from

to

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
```

And in `SplashActivity` get `Action` from Intent and then check if the Action is `android.intent.action.VIEW` Then Open your `MainActivity` and send your file from `SplashActivity` to `MainActivity`.

That's it

Answer (score 0):

You can't change launcher activity from manifest file. You can set more than one `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>` in intent-filter but You have to set a default activity.

But there is a way you can solve your problem...

1. Make a launcher activity with No UI and open the activity with condition in onCreate method.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Intent intent;
   if (condition) {
   intent = new Intent(this, ClassA.class);
   } else {
   intent = new Intent(this, ClassB.class);
   }
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();
   }
   ```

> OR

2. In your splash activity write condition before setContentView method.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Intent intent;
   if (condition) {
   setContentView();
   } else {
   intent = new Intent(this, ClassB.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();
   }

   }
   ```

Hope this will help you.